# Ninja build in xText

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to define a grammar for [ninja build](http://martine.github.com/ninja/) with xtext.

There are three tricky points that I can't answer.

- Indentations by tab:

How to handle indentations. A *rule* in a ninja build file might have several variable definitions with preceding tab spacing (similar to make files). This becomes a problem when the language has SL comments, ignores white-spaces and does indentation by tabs (python, make,...)

```
cflags = -g
rule cc
  command = gcc $cflags -c $in -o $out
```

- Cross referencing reserved set of variable names:

There exists a set of reserved variables. Auto-complete should be able to reference both the reserved and the user defined set of variables.

```
command = gcc $cflags -c $in -o $out
```

- Autocompleting cross referenced variable names which aren't seperated with WS

org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals hides WS tokens. ID tokens are seperated by white spaces. But in ninja script (similar to make files) the parsing should be done with longest matching variable name.

```
some_var = some_value
command  = $some_var.h
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Still need help with this one?

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167834/xtext-grammar-for-language-with-significant-semantic-whitespace

Comment: Not actively but an answer would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Xtext 2.8.0 release: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/releasenotes.html

The `Whitespace-Aware Languages` section states:

> Xtext 2.8 supports languages in which whitespace is used to specify
>   the structure, e.g. using indentation to delimit code blocks as in
>   Python. This is done through synthetic tokens defined in the grammar:
>
> ```
> terminal BEGIN: 'synthetic:BEGIN';
> terminal END: 'synthetic:END';
> ```
>
> These tokens can be used like other terminals in grammar rules:
>
> ```
> WhitespaceAwareBlock:
>     BEGIN
>         ...
>     END;
> ```
>
> The new example language Home Automation available in the Eclipse examples (File → New → Example → Xtext Examples) demonstrates this concept. It allows code like the following:
>
> ```
> Rule 'Report error' when Heater.error then
>     var String report
>     do
>         Thread.sleep(500)
>         report = HeaterDiagnostic.readError
>     while (report == null)
>     println(report)
> ```
>
> More details are found in the documentation.